# Will this log4j configuration file create application.log files appended with the timestamp?

Tags: date, logging, configuration, log4j

I have a log4j configuration file that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' debug="false">

  <appender name="consoleAppender"
  class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d
         %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
  </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="fileAppender"
       class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
  <param name="File" value="/var/output/logs/application.log"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
   </layout>
   </appender>

<logger name="connect.testJava" additivity="false" >
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
</logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I wanted to basically create logs with the format application.log like application2013-06-12 12:12:00.log or something like that. The above configuration does not seem to be doing that. Can someone please help me out and tell me what I might be doing wrong? I am just about a couple of hours into log4j, so sorry if this question sounds too naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. Just wait till midnight and a new file will be created. The day's file will remain application.log